# find max value between three columns

Tags: python, pandas, ambiguous

I'm trying find max value between three columns, but I get the error (The truth value of a Series is ambiguous).

I have a dataframe like this:

| TR0 | TR1 | TR2 | TR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3.25 | 2.19 | 0.15 |  |
| 3.0 | 0 | 0.14 |  |

I need put in column "TR" the max value between columns TR0, TR1, TR2.
I'm trying this:

```
df.loc[:,'TR'] = max(df.loc[:,'TR0'], df.loc[:,'TR1'], df.loc[:,'TR2'])
```

but get the message *The truth value of a Series is ambiguous*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your using the Python max function with Pandas series as arguments.  It was not designed for that.

Use the Pandas data frame max method instead:

```python
df['TR'] = df[['TR0', 'TR1', 'TR2']].max(axis=1)
```